# How can I use (this).getName() like a string?

Tags: ajax, json, post, http-post

Im trying to use `(this).getName();`, instead of 'e3000', and I have to use '' around `(this).getName();` instead of 'e3000' like It is know.
How can I use `(this).getName();` with '' instead of 'e3000'?

```
data: JSON.stringify([{ 'e3000': {'name': (this).getName(), 'x': (this).getPosition().x, 'y': (this).getPosition().y, 'plan': '1'}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify([{'"' + (this).getName() + '"': {'name': (this).getName(), 'x': (this).getPosition().x, 'y': (this).getPosition().y, 'plan': '1'}}])
```

Comment: It should do the trick if I understood your question correctly :)

Comment: Sunden I get this error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id